# CSS won't load on iPhone Refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 20px) and (max-width: 375px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/detailsLayout280.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 20px) and (max-width: 375px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="css/copy280.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 700px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="css/detailsLayout320.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 700px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="css/copy320.css" />
```

I have a page where the CSS won't load initially on an iPhone, but if I switch the orientation back and forth it will.

Then by clicking refresh, again the CSS doesn't load until I do the orientation change again.

This happens on a secondary page only. The home page is set up in much the same way and it works fine.

I also have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

which I need for the iPad CSS. If I take this out the problem goes away for the phone (although zoomed out), but I need it for the iPad.

Why won't the CSS load unless I change the orientation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the pixel density as smartphones now have 700px+ in width.

Browser specific

```
(-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

A quick example of how you might apply this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 20px) and (max-width: 375px) and (orientation:portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="css/detailsLayout280.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do development and change your css often then change your href path so it contains a question mark and something varying there after. An example that uses `php` is below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

This way, every time your `href` will be different. It is, however disabling browser's caching ability, and it is not good in production. In production, make sure your css file has version in the name of the file.

Comment: How do you know he's using php?

Comment: I thought I was missing something. :)